# Enum with .default Option

Tags: swift, swift3

This question is basically to study, there is no "why?" or "instead of ..."

In Swift 3 it is very common to use the .default, exemplifying:

```
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default
    // from UIStatusBarStyle.default
```

And I was thinking, how?
In my tests I did not succeed, I try something like:

```
    class Test {
        enum Options {
            case light, default // bad world
        }
    }
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do like this:

```
class Test {
  enum Options:Int {
    case `default`
    case lightContent

  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome. If it helps you then please tick the accept button :)